# SQL Server 2012 - Datetimeoffset field want to find noon time for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, time-format

I have a database that sample well levels hourly each day for numerous wells.   The datetime is in a datetimeoffset field called sampleTime.
I want to filter the data so that I will find 18:00:00 utc time for each day.   I cannot seem to find a way to set the time correctly to look for this in an SQL statement.  We have SQL Server 2012.

Here is what I have tried.

```
SELECT
    wellID, 
    CAST(sampleTime AS time(0)) as "welltime", 
    CAST(sampleTime AS date) as welldate, 
    sampleTime, waterLevel 
FROM 
    dbo.Real_Time_Water_Level_Data
WHERE 
    'welltime' = CAST('18:00:00' AS time)
ORDER BY 
    welldate
```

I get an message

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I am assuming that is in my method of trying to set the '18:00:00' as a what I am looking for. I have tried it without the CAST and using a CONVERT but also getting errors.

What I really would love to get is the local noon time record for each day but I know that I would have to deal with CST and CDT  and just decide to get the specific one of 18:00:00

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
wellID, 
CAST(sampleTime AS time(0)) as welltime, 
CAST(sampleTime AS date) as welldate, 
sampleTime, waterLevel 
FROM dbo.Real_Time_Water_Level_Data
WHERE CAST(sampleTime AS time(0)) = CAST('18:00:00' AS time)
ORDER BY CAST(sampleTime AS date)
```

You can't use an `alias` in the `where` clause. You query has been modified to that effect.

Comment: Perfection.  I have some other queries that someone gave me and I always wondered why they  did not just just the alias that they had create.  This explains that.     I have learned two things today.   THANKS!!!!!!!!

Comment: So now  I can get the "daily" data at 18:00 utc.    I am using SSRS 2012   and I want the report to have a control so that the user can do something like a checkbox to say if checked they only will get the daily data at 18:00  If not checked they will get the hourly data.  There does not seem to be a parameter like the checkbox.  Any thoughts?